# Responsive size with aspect ratio and query

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have 2 divs, left one is fluid and has aspect ratio, right one has fixed width. I want below 600px for the right div to fall under left div (and become 100% width), while the left div must maintain aspect ratio as window shrinks. And the wrapper div must have height of both child divs obviously. Is it possible to do this with css?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="a">
    This is your div with the specified aspect ratio.
  </div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ke6duke/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box to achieve this.

```
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper .a{
  flex-grow: 1;
  // Presentational styles
  background: deepskyblue url('https://res.cloudinary.com/sivadass/image/upload/v1493620046/dummy-products/cauliflower.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
.wrapper .b{
  flex-basis: 400px;
  background: #333;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 600px){
  .wrapper{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Check the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w6Ljh6qb/16/)

Comment: Second would need to stay 300px high after it gets below. Just first div should retain previous aspect ratio.

Comment: is setting the fixed height to the second div using breakpoints suffice your needs?

Comment: You've missed the dot prefix for class name, that's why the style didn't take effect. Check this fork: https://jsfiddle.net/1pmhhjvn/2/

Comment: This doesnt have my initial requirements: wrapper: max-width: 1000px;
  max-height: 400px; , and first div still doesnt retain aspect ratio after second div gets below.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I hope it helps someone.